# Reading Header of AU File - C

Tags: c, audio

I'm trying to read in the header for a `.au` file, in C, and I have all the values stored in a `struct` but am having trouble converting them to Little Endian format.

I stumbled upon a method, `ntohl` that is supposed to take the bytes and convert them to the host format, but I keep getting an error when compiling my program.

`undefined reference to 'ntohl'`

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct header
{
    char magic[5];
    int offset;
    int size;
    int encoding;
    int rate;
    int channels;
};

int main()
{
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    struct header au;
    char path[10];

    printf("Enter name of file to be processed: ");
    scanf("%s", path);

    fin = fopen(path, "r");
    fout = fopen("out.au","w");

    fscanf(fin, "%s %d %d %d %d %d", &au.magic, &au.offset, &au.size, &au.encoding, &au.rate, &au.channels);
    printf("%s\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", au.magic, ntohl(au.offset), ntohl(au.size), ntohl(au.encoding), ntohl(au.rate), ntohl(au.channels));
}
```

Am I reading in the header values correctly?

Answer (score 1):

On [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl) OS `ntohl` is declared in `arpa/inet.h` (or `netinet/in.h`) header file. On [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it's `Winsock2.h`

As for correctness of reading the header, it is incorrect. You are doing `fscanf(fin, "%s %d %d %d %d %d...` which is an attempt to read numbers in their textual representation, separated by spaces, which is totally not how [`AU` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_file_format) is represented. This file type is a binary file and should be read as a binary using `fread` for example.